# Room DB TypeConverter GSon: Unable to create instance of class

Tags: java, gson, android-room

I'm facing this problem:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create instance of class java.text.NumberFormat. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a no-args constructor may fix this problem.`

It's referred with a data class of mytable "patient":

```
@Entity(tableName = "patient")
@Parcelize
data class Patient(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var dataPatientList: @RawValue List<DataPatient> = listOf()
) : Parcelable, Serializable
```

The DataPatient class:

```
data class DataPatient(
    val where: String,
    val photoList: MutableList<DataPatientPhotoTaken> = mutableListOf()
): Serializable {

    data class DataPatientPhotoTaken(
        val dateTime: SimpleDateFormat,
        var hasBeenUploadedRedcap: Boolean = false,
        val focusPoint: String,
        val bitmapNotCompressed: Bitmap,
    ): Serializable
}
```

I've implemented a TypeConverter using Gson to be able to store dataPatientList:

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromDataPatientList(value: List<DataPatient>): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<DataPatient>>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(value, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toDataPatientList(value: String): List<DataPatient> {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<DataPatient>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(value, type) // <----- HERE THE CRASH LOG
    }
}
```

The crash log does not work with line `return gson.fromJson(value, type)`. 
Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: Why is the dateTime field of type SimpleDateFormat? That makes no sense.

Comment: @RealSkeptic is that the problem?

Comment: Well, that's where the problem occurs. But rather than trying to solve it by finding a way to serialize a date format, you'll solve it better if you use an actual `LocalDateTime` or whatever the dateTime field is supposed to be.